# Install/Enable Adobe Flash Player debug version in Ubuntu 14.04 for Firefox (if possible for Chrome too)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash, adobe

I found many different solutions similar to each other on the web, but obviously they are outdated. It's suggested to download the flash player from here https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer (Nothing told on the page whether it's debug or not) and to copy libflashplayer.so to (regarding firefox) /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins. I already have the same .so in  /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer and symlink under mozilla plugins folder referring to this .so.

Is it possible to enable debug support under Ubuntu 14.04 at least for firefox?

Comment: Have you tried copying the .so?  It may not be indentical.

Comment: I compared them by kompare

Answer (score 0):

Yes sir, debug is possible, but more effectively, you can get adobe flash for Mozilla Firefox in the Ubuntu Software Center. Just go in and search "Adobe Flash," then install and restart Mozilla. And that's it! If this works for you, make sure to vote up and check it so that other people can see this if they want to know the same question!

Comment: I already have Adobe Flash plugin installed in Software Center. Anyway this version checker (https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html) shows me that I have no debug.

Comment: There should be an option on the Flash page in USC that says to install the debug version